# Running a program on many different computers automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scientific-computing

I am new to scientific computing and am working on a project which involves running many simulations. The infrastructure with which I am provided for this is about 20 different linux machines which all share storage. What I've been doing so far is the horrendously inefficient task of ssh'ing into each computer individually and running the simulation programs manually.

Given that I have a list of all the names of the computers and the same password for each one, could someone provide a sparse outline of how to go about automatically running many executables on many linux machines? An example of what I must do right now for each simulation is:

```
$ ssh username@computername.university.edu

username@computername.university.edu's password:

username@computername:~$ ./executeprogram 2 5 8 &

username@computername:~$ ./executeprogram 2 5 10 &

username@computername:~$ ./executeprogram 2 5 12 &
```

Where the numbers are just arguments the simulation `executeprogram` in the home directory takes in. Hopefully you can appreciate that for 20 different `computername`'s this is pretty tedious to do by hand. Apologies if it is unclear what I am asking; I ask here because I do not have the vocabulary to know what is I should be googling to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: First thing first, set up your *public ssh keys* for passwordless operation. Then write a script that runs `ssh user@computer remote-program arg1 arg2...` for many different computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things to this question.

First step would be to install your ssh key on those machines to avoid having to type the password every time. Assuming you've already [setup a ssh key](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2):

```
ssh-copy-id username@computername.university.edu
```

Then, you don't need to ssh into the machine to run commands. You can pass it as part of the initial `ssh` call. e.g.:

```
ssh username@computername.university.edu ./executeprogram 2 5 8
```

But if executeprogram is long-running, this might not be ideal as it would wait for it to finish before exiting the ssh connection. [There are a few ways around this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

Now all thats left would be to write the above into a single script.

Comment: Thank you! Okay, so then in the course of learning how to actually write the script I will find that I can run tmux remotely, run three instances of ./executeprogram in tmux, then send-keys ctrl-d to exit tmux and the simulations can continue running after exiting the connection?

Comment: See the `screen` command for runnings things in the background. Also see the answer from Anubis. He raised a good point, in that you might not want to permanently leave your ssh key on university servers.

Comment: Since the OP seems to be sweeping accross multiple parameters, I suggest pairing your answer with the use of GNU parallel. With its `--sshloginfile` option, it is possible to run the same program with different arguments on different machines automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If your main problem is having to enter the password for each SSH session, there are two quick options.

1. Copying your SSH pub key to each of the remote machines.They won't ask for password again when trying to login. (You might not prefer this for a temporary work. As your public key will be permanently added to the authorized_keys file of the remote machines)
2. Using [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) to handle the password prompt. This is nice for a quick and dirty work.

   ```
   sshpass -p <mypassword> ssh user@ip <REMOTE COMMAND>
   ```

You can run multiple commands through SSH using `heredocs` as below,

```
sshpass -p <mypassword> ssh user@ip bash<<EOF
<command 1>
<command 2>
...
EOF
```